# Quotient groups from the orbit category

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, normal-subgroups

The orbit category $\text{Orb}_G$ is defined in example 1.3.15 of [Riehl](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf).

It seems to me that the quotient group $G$ modulo $H$ corresponds to the full subcategory of $(\text{Orb}_G)^{\text{op}}$ on the object $G/H.$ Basically I'm wondering if this is correct, and if so, whether there is a way to reframe things to avoid the messy appearance of opposite categories. My reasoning is as follows:

The objects of $\text{Orb}_G$ are left $G$-sets $G/H$ (for subgroups $H \subseteq G$) and the arrows are the $G$-equivariant maps. Here $G/H = \{gH | g \in G \}$ has left action $g' \bullet gH = (g'g)H$ where $gH= \{gh | h \in H \}$ is a left coset.

It seems that the following conditions hold

1. For each arrow $G/H \overset{\alpha}\to G/K$ there exists $\gamma \in G$ such that $\alpha(gH)=g\gamma K$ for each $gH \in G/H.$ Here $\gamma^{-1} H \gamma \subseteq K.$
2. Given any $\gamma \in G$ with $\gamma^{-1} H \gamma \subseteq K$ we can define arrow $G/H \overset{\alpha^{\gamma}}\to G/K$ such that $\alpha^{\gamma}(gH)=g\gamma K$ for each $gH \in G/H.$

When $H$ is a normal subgroup we have $\gamma^{-1} H \gamma \subseteq H$ for each $\gamma \in G.$ In this case each arrow of $\text{Orb}_G$ with domain $G/H$ also has codomain $G/H,$ and the set of such arrows will be $\{\alpha^{\gamma} | \gamma \in G \}$ where $\alpha^{\gamma}(gH)=g\gamma H.$

The quotient group $G$ modulo $H$ has elements $gH$ and group multiplication defined so that $(gH) * (g'H)=\alpha^{g'}(gH)=(gg')H=\alpha^{g'} \alpha^{g} H.$

If we take the full subcategory $S$ of $\text{Orb}_G$ on the object $G/H$ its arrows will correspond to these endomorphisms $\alpha^{g},$ but these seem to compose in the opposite order to how multiplication works in $G$ modulo $H.$ Hence $G$ modulo $H$ (as a single object category) is equivalent to $S^{op}.$

Does this seem correct ?

Comment: I thank you again for your YouTube videos, they really helped me last year

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: What if $\bullet$ acted on the other side? It should get rid of the contravariance, or rather, hide it elsewhere (I don't think you can rephrase things to freely change the variance of an identification... duality is more complicated than that ;-) )

Comment: Yea I think that makes sense. Just wanted to check the op wasn't appearing because I made some kind of slipup

Comment: This is just the standard left/right action issue, c.f. if you want to trivialize the tangent bundle of a Lie group: Riehl defines $Mor(H,K)$ to be the morphisms equivariant for the *left action* of $G$, and hence on the trivial subgroup $\{e_G\}$ these maps are given by the natural right action of $G$ on itself, so you get $Mor(\{e_G\},\{e_G\}) = G^{\text{op}}$.

Comment: iirc Orb_G is also equivalent to the category of G-actions (left or right, I don't recall)